# How many sets that differs in at least two elements are there?

Tags: combinatorics

Let vector $a_i=(a_i^1,...,a_i^n)$, where $a_i^j\in\{0,1\}\forall j\in\{1,..,n\}$.

Let set $A=\{a_1,...,a_i,...,a_m\}$. $|A|=m$. What is $\max(m)$ for each dimension $n$, if we require that every vector in $A$ must differ from any other vector in at least two terms:

$$\forall i,j\in\{1,...,m\}, \\ a_i-a_j \ \text{must be at least a two dimensional vector}.$$

For example, if $n=2$, then $\max m=2$: $A=\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$

If $n=3$, then $\max m=4$: $A=\{(0,0,1),(1,0,0),(1,1,1),(0,1,0)\}$

Please correct me if there are anything unclear about this simple problem that I cannot solve.

---

If we only require one different term , then $\max m=2^n$

Comment: Look up Hamming distance.

Comment: @martycohen Thank you, this is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Math is like magic in that knowing the true name for something gives you power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We shall prove that, if a set $S$ of vectors in $\{0,1\}^n$ is such that any two elements of $S$ differ by at least $2$ coordinates, then $$|S|\leq 2^{n-1}\,.$$
Note that the bound is sharp by considering the set $$S=\Big\{v\in\{0,1\}^n\,\Big|\,v\text{ has an even number of }1\text{s}\Big\}\,.$$  (In fact, there are only two maximal sets $S$, the one above and its complement in $\{0,1\}^n$.)

Partition $\{0,1\}^n$ into $2^{n-1}$ sets of the form
$$P_{x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n}:=\big\{\left(0,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n\right),\left(1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n\right)\big\}\,.$$
If $|S|>2^{n-1}$, then there exists $P_{x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n}$ which contains two elements of $S$, and this is a contradiction.

**P.S.:**  Apparently, the general case is an open problem.  See a table [here](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/codes/binary-1.html).  However, a similar argument can be used to show that $$A_2(n,d)\leq \left\lceil 2^{n-d+1}\right\rceil\,,$$
where $A_k(n,d)$ is the maximum number of vectors in a $k$-ary code of word length $n$ and with Hamming distance $d$.

Comment: Thank you Batominovski, this is very helpful. Are there any "stricter" upper bound for this open problem?